# Merge two arrays without sorting using array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, merge

I am trying to merge to arrays without sorting (add one then another) using pointer method but its just printing the first array and then garbage values. What i am trying to do is just combine 2 arrays in one big array. No sorting required(at least for now).

```
void getarray(int*,int);
int merge(int*,int*,int,int,int*);
main()
{
int a[10],b[10],c[20];
int i,j,n,m,size;
clrscr();
printf("Enter no. of elements in FIRST array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
getarray(a,n);
printf("Enter no. of elements in SECOND array: ");
scanf("%d",&m);
getarray(b,m);
merge(a,b,n,m,c);
printf("\nMerged Array: \n");
for(i=0;i<n+m;i++)
{
    printf("\t%d\t",c[i]);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
void getarray(int *x, int y)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<y;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",x+i);
}
}

int merge(int *a, int *b,int n,int m,int *c)
{
   int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    *(c+i) = *(a+i);
}
   for(j=i;j<i+m;j++)
   {
    *(c+j) = *(b+j);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth -- Well now I don't _want_ to post the answer I just found, since Devlin would learn so much more by finding it him/her-self.

Comment: dude i have tried all those stuff. i know the drill. still not getting picture. so please if you wanna help, go ahead.

Comment: You are beginning your index to b at n (instead of 0).  That can't be good.

Comment: And @OliCharlesworth dude i will try my best not to post a question before triple checking it. learned from the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int merge(int *a, int *b,int n,int m,int *c)
{
   int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    *(c+i) = *(a+i);
}
   for(j=0;j<m;j++)
   {
    *(c+n+j) = *(b+j);
   }
}
```

Comment: You were getting your indices confused on the second for loop.

Comment: thanks man. i am still learning. so pardon my rookie mistake.

Comment: @Devlin  Don't worry about it.  Some of the SO people can be crabbykins.  We all have mistakes we miss that others can see clearly.  Happens all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use (assuming c is large enough):

```
void merge(int *a, int *b,int n,int m,int *c) {
  memcpy(c,   a, sizeof(int)*n);
  memcpy(c+n, b, sizeof(int)*m);
}
```

You would need to include `string.h`.